# String and pointer in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

Pointer are the variables which stores address.

```
char *ptr = "string";
printf("%s",ptr);
```

In this code snippet, the whole string was printing without dereferencing. Why was this happening?

And in this case the characters are printing it was working as expected just like an array.

```
char *ptr = "string";
printf("%c",*ptr);
```

What is the difference in these two cases

Comment: any introductory text book on C will explain this

Comment: Time to read the documentation of printf. What argument type does it expect for %c, what for %s specifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format string "%s" expects that the corresponding argument  points to the first character of a string and the function `printf` outputs the string until the terminating zero character `'\0'` is encountered.

In fact this call of `printf`

```
char *ptr = "string";
printf("%s",ptr);
```

is logically implemented under the hood the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *ptr = "string";

    for ( char *tmp = ptr; *tmp != '\0'; ++tmp )
    {
        printf( "%c", *tmp );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The format string `"%c"` expect an object of the type char and the function `printf` outputs the object as a character.

Comment: "is logically implemented under the hood the following way" - no, it really isn't.

Comment: @Alnitak It is interesting why?:)

Comment: because internally printf would use a plain `fputc` call (or make a direct write of the character to the output buffer).  It absolutely would not make a recursive call to `printf` with a `%c` specifier.

Comment: @Alnitak Logically it is the same. I used printf because in the question also is used printf to output a character. What you have mentioned are implementation details that has nothing common with the demonstrated idea.

Comment: Writing "logically" in front of what you've written doesn't make it so.

Comment: @Alnitak It makes it so. The meaning of the word is well-known. What you are speaking about is implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

The format string (`%c` or `%s`) tell it what to treat the parameters as.

The `%s` is for a string - so walks the pointer printing each character until it hits a `\0`.

The `%c` prints one character only.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a [string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-string-literals?view=msvc-160), when you do `char *ptr = "string";`, which is a null-terminated sequence of characters.

The format argument `%s` prints a string until `\0` is found, while `%c` prints a single character.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%c", *ptr);
```

is slightly misleading. To make it clear you want one character out of the string...

```
printf("%c", ptr[0]);
```

So for the `%c` you dereference one char.

The `%s` dereferences the pointer, increasing it by a char until it reaches a `\0`.

The `%s` is equivalent to something like this, using `%c`:

```
void printf_s(char *cp) {

    while(*cp)
        printf("%c", *(cp++));
}
```

The expression `*(cp++)` says: cp[0], cp[1],...,cp[n].